# How to solve this issue "Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install"

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Actually i want to run JavaFx on eclipse but all my effort is vain when a pop appears: 
[image]

I applied every steps that I learnt from this site on my Eclipse like set java compiler, java build path, JDK version 1.8 and many more but all in vain. Anyone please help me to to remove this error how to solve this issue.

I would be thankful to you if you will tell me in steps.

Comment: How are you launching Eclipse? From the command line? And how did you install Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the Java you are using inside Eclipse, rather it is the Java you are using to launch Eclipse itself.

As the message says you need to either make Java 8 the default Java on your system or you can edit the 'eclipse.ini' file in your Eclipse installation and set the path the Java 8 there. In the 'eclipse.ini' add:

```
-vm
/path/to/java
```

where '/path/to/java' is the full path of your Java 8.

Note: This line must be **before** any -vmargs line in the eclipse.ini. You must put the -vm and the path on separate lines.